# strmatch with multiple conditions

Tags: matlab

I want to find out the row number with the conditions below.

**Edit 1** example

- Column 1 = 'A'
- Column 2 = 'B'
- Column 3 = 'C'

Array:

```
x = { 'A'    'B'   'E';
      'A'    'B'    'C';
      'A'    'E'    'C';
      'B'    'F'    'E'}
```

I want to find out the row number with the conditions below (row 2).

- Column 1 = 'A'
- Column 2 = 'B'
- Column 3 = 'C'

How can I use `strmatch` or other function to find it out in MATLAB?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Does not appear to be a duplicate of the aforementioned question. Perhaps the answer is somewhat relevant but the question is completely different and this one has a better suited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case:

```
rows = find(strcmp(x(:,1),'A') & strcmp(x(:,2),'B') & strcmp(x(:,3),'C'));
```

If you always have exactly three columns, and if each cell always contains a single letter, you can alternatively use:

```
rows = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, cell2mat(x), 'ABC'),2));
```

Comment: (1) my data always have at least 3 columns but (2) not all cells contain a single letter only.